# Slow posting speed don't know why?

Tags: facebook, multithreading, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-5.0

thanks to lots of help out there I managed to create a **Facebook application** and a control panel **desktop app** to publish posts using it,, i've sent it to my clients and they admired the app,, one of my apps have about more than **20.000** subscriber and to publish a normal text post to their time line it would take the desktop ( control panel) app quite about **13 hours** to accomplish this GIVEN That my internet speed is quit good ( about **2 Mbps**) and i only publish **normal text** ( no photos included )

I am using **fb-c#-sdk** v 6.x
I am creating every post request asynchronously.
I've increased the process and thread priority to the maximum ( even sub-threads).

Is it a Facebook graph issue or rule that enforces this ?

**My question would be** what is the actual problem that cause this slow behavior and any suggestions to make it better ?

I am using a very straightforward approach something like this :

```
string[] tokens; //--> intialized from values within an online db
foreach(var token in tokens){
    await FaceBookManager.PostAsync("status goes here", token);
}
```

and the `FacebookManager` class:

```
public class FacebookManager {
    public async static Task<bool> PostAsync(string status, string token) {
        FacebokClient fb = new FacebookClient(token){ // intialization goes here };
        return await Task.Run(() => { 
                                      try {
                                        fb.PostTaskAsync(); 
                                        return true;
                                      }
                                      catch
                                      {
                                        return false;
                                      }
                                    });
    } 
}
```

This is not the exact same code but it's the same approach I take. For every posting operation I call an `async` method which creates a sub thread...

Comment: So, you are expecting us to profile your application for you without giving us any code at all?

Comment: I've added my code approach,, hope this helps.

Comment: When you say this is not the exact same code have you tested the code you've posted to seen whether the same issue is exhibited?

Comment: yap,, it did the same... took about 12 hours !